# If I have a mixture of potassium hydroxide and sodium hypochlorite, what will be the result of adding citric acid or ascorbic acid?

Tags: acid-base

I have a cleaning chemical that is $\pu{10\%}$ potassium hydroxide ($\ce{KOH}$}) and $\pu{5\%}$ sodium hypochlorite ($\ce{NaClO}$). What is the result if I add citric acid ($\ce{C6H8O7}$) or ascorbic acid ($\ce{C6H8O6}$)? My goal is to neutralize the high pH of the potassium hydroxide without creating dangerous byproducts. I do not have a background in chemistry. How do I determine the result of the mass balance equation?

$\ce{KOH + NaClO + C6H8O7 -> ?}$
$\ce{KOH + NaClO + C6H8O6 -> ?}$

Comment: Chlorine gas maybe?

Comment: For non chemists, I rather suggest sufficient washing a/o dilution and neutralization of eventual residues by diluted vinegar. Processing it at high concentration can cause violent effects, mostly being attacked by obsolete yet powerful chemical weapon of chlorine ( Somme 1915 ).

Comment: The proposed equations with three substances is not possible, The acids, whatever their structure, react with $\ce{KOH}$ and also with $\ce{NaClO}$ but these two equations are occurring independently from one another. But the reaction with $\ce{NaClO}$ produces chlorine  $\ce{Cl2}$ which is a dangerous gas. Try not to do such a mixture !

Answer (score 4):

The reason hypochlorites are kept alkaline is to prevent evolution of chlorine gas, $\ce{Cl2}$.

- Any attempt to make the cleaners less alkaline will release poisonous $\ce{Cl2}$, *unless*
- A reactant combines with the chlorine, preventing its evolution... thus making the cleaner useless as a bleach and disinfectant, *or*
- The worst outcome: the reactants eliminate the chlorine, but produce even *more toxic and volatile products*. For example, the reaction of hypochlorites and household (aqueous) ammonia produces hazardous chloramine, or even hydrazine. See [Science ABC](https://www.scienceabc.com/pure-sciences/what-happens-when-you-mix-bleach-and-ammonia.html) for more detail on that reaction.